# Process multiple csv lines with java

Tags: java, csv, for-loop, collections

I have a file which I write a csv values each in a new line into. The result looks smth like that:

```
Hello;kind;world
Mister;John;Doe
```

and so on. I also have a class with a constructor taking each partial value, e.g. `John` as a parameter:

```
public MyClass(String first, String second, String third) {}
```

As a result I need a `Collection<MyClass>`. While processing I iterate over each csv line and then in an inner for loop over the particular line values after splitting it with a `;` like that:

```
Collection<String> csvLines = Files.readAllLines(pathToMyFile);
for (String csvLine : csvLines) {
 String[] csvLineSplitted = csvLine.split(";");
 for (int i = 0; i < csvLineSplitted.length; i++) {
  String value = scvLineSPlitted[i]; //This can be the above mentioned value, e.g. 'John'
 }
}
```

How can I create an object of type `MyClass` with each of this particular parameter and then store it in the `Collection<MyCLass> result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with *Streams* too:

```
private class MyClass {
    private String first;
    private String second;

    MyClass(String first, String second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
    }

}


List<MyClass> list = Files.lines(path)
        .map(line -> line.split(";"))
        .map(splittedLine -> new MyClass(splittedLine[0], splittedLine[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

If you got more than two columns just modify the second map operator to fit your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Just define a class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public MyClass(String param1, String param2) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then use that class when you iterate over your CSV data:

```
Collection<String> csvLines = Files.readAllLines(pathToMyFile);
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String csvLine : csvLines) {
    String[] csvLineSplitted = csvLine.split(";");
    MyClass node = new MyClass(csvLineSplitted[0], csvLineSplitted[1]);
    list.add(node);
}
```

Note that I am assuming here that your data only has two columns.  If the actual data has several columns, then your approach of iterating in a for loop makes more sense.

Comment: It actually has more than two columns, this one was just an example. See my edit